# Spring Boot App: Login to MySQL database on Azure using system assigned managed identity

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-mysql-database

I followed [this article](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/app-service/tutorial-connect-msi-azure-database.md) to create a system assigned managed identity for an app service on Azure and made the necessary AD authrization for MySQL database. The link has a java code to generate token and connect to MySQL, however, that code is not handy to be injected as a Bean to all DAO classes. Moreover, with that code, you need to check expiry of token with almost every call.

Does anyone know an implementation which takes care of renewing token and which can be used as a Bean?

Comment: Hi @KartikBhiwapurkar-MT, It did not solve the issue. When I deploy the webapp on the app service it throws error : "Azure AD access token is not valid for user"

Comment: I followed this website: https://www.azureblue.io/how-to-authenicated-aad-identity-against-postgres-using-spring-boot and it worked when I deployed my spring boot web-app to azure app service.

Is the RestController advice, as suggested by you, required?

Comment: I would suggest you to please try doing it, if it helps then fine and if not, then no issues.

Comment: Hi @RanbirSinha, did the suggested solution work for you? Do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot or else do accept it for helping other community members.

Answer (score 0):

•   To be frank, I tried to login to an `Azure SQL DB server using a system assigned managed identity from a .Net Framework console application` and that truly worked for me, i.e., it responded with code 0 successfully. I also checked further in the application insights workspace to find out whether the connection truly happened or not and the connection was made successfully without any issue.

•   Thus, in your scenario, you have deployed a web app service in Azure with code runtime as Java since you want to develop a spring boot app and create a system assigned managed identity to it and an Azure MySql DB server also to connect to. After deploying this infrastructure and following the Github documentation that you have posted, I would suggest you to please include the `RestControllerAdvice` section under `TokenRefreshException.java` as below: -

```
  package com.example.spring.security.jwt.advice;
  import java.util.Date;
  import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
  import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
  import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
  import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestControllerAdvice;
  import org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest;
  import com.bezkoder.spring.security.jwt.exception.TokenRefreshException;
  @RestControllerAdvice
  public class TokenControllerAdvice {
  @ExceptionHandler(value = TokenRefreshException.class)
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)
  public ErrorMessage handleTokenRefreshException(TokenRefreshException ex, WebRequest request) {
   return new ErrorMessage(
    HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN.value(),
    new Date(),
    ex.getMessage(),
    request.getDescription(false));
    }
   }
```

This would tell a **controller** that the object returned is automatically serialized into JSON and passed it to the **‘HttpResponse’** object. You only need to return Java body object instead of **ResponseEntity** object. But the status could be always `OK (200)` although the data corresponds to exception signal (`404 – Not Found for example`).

Hence, using the above section, you can manage the renewing of a token in your spring boot application. For more detailed information on this, I would suggest you to please refer to the below link: -

https://www.javainuse.com/webseries/spring-security-jwt/chap7